# Matplotlib plot does not show lines when adding in annotations

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to figure out how matplotlib annotaitons work and I tried the following:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, autoscale_on=False, ylim=(1, 9000000))

plt.plot(df['month'], df['France'], label='France')
plt.plot(df['month'], df['Germany'], label='Germany')

ax.annotate('test', xy=(100, 1000), xytext=(3, 1.5),
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),
            )

fig.set_size_inches(15, 7)
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.show()
```

It is giving me a plot area, but is not showing the lines or the annotations.  Any thoughts?

The following works and gives me a graph, but no annotations, obviously:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(autoscale_on=False, ylim=(1, 9000000))

plt.plot(df['month'], df['France'], label='France')
plt.plot(df['month'], df['Germany'], label='Germany')

fig.set_size_inches(15, 7)
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `arrowstyle’='-'` (or `'->'`, or `'<-'` or `'<->'` depending on what type of line or arrow you want) to your `arrowprops` dictionary?
Note also that the `xy` coordinates should be in data units, so it may be that `(100, 1000)` is not within your axes area (I don't know the range of values of your data.)

Comment: My x axis is date time objects and my y axis goes up to 9M

Comment: How did you choose 100 and 3 as your x-coordinates for the arrow head and text location?

Comment: It was arbitrary, i was just trying to get the text to appear

Comment: To check if this is the problem, you could specify both pairs of coordinates in fractional axis coordinates (0-1) for each x and y, and set `xycoords='axes fraction'` and `textcoords='axes fraction'` as arguments to `annotate`